# Simple Form Configuration

Tags: simple-form

In simple_form.rb how do I set time_zone_priority and country_priority. The following does not work.

```
config.time_zone_priority = ["IN", "US", "CA", "UK"]

config.country_priority = ['India', 'United States']
```

In the view file, however, the following works:

```
= f.country_select :country_code, priority: %w(IN US CA UK)
```

Please assist

Comment: what version of SimpleForm are you using? did you restart your server after changing SimpleForm's initializer?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too just now. Then, in the initializer, when I tried the country codes instead of the full country names, it worked.

```
config.country_priority = ['IN', 'US', 'CA', 'UK']
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles here, for the same reason as I did 11 or so years after the initial post, looking for prioritising multiple Time Zones. Previous answers don't seem to address the Time Zone part of the question and as in original post, the following  `config.time_zone_priority = ["IN", "US", "CA", "UK"]` does not work.

This is how I did it in config -> initializers -> simple_form.rb

```
    config.time_zone_priority = [
    ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Paris"],
    ActiveSupport::TimeZone["London"]
    # etc...
  ]
```

Using ActionView doc for reference : https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-time_zone_select

The time_zone_select helper looks very useful also.